# C# DeserializeObject change class attribute name

Tags: c#, deserialization

Hello I have one json text one attribute includes `$type`. I want to change it to `type` in my response but it is again written as `$type`.

```
  public class DocumentDTO
     {
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public List<DocumentInfo> Documents { get; set; }

     }
    public class DocumentInfo
    {
        public string DocumentState { get; set; }
        public DocumentData DocumentData { get; set; }
        public string DocumentAsBase64 { get; set; }
    }
    public class DocumentData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$type")]
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<DocumentField> Fields { get; set; }
    }
    public class DocumentField
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$type")]
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string SuspiciousSymbols { get; set; }
        public string RecognizedValue { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I am deserializing like below code

```
DocumentDTO documentResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentDTO>(jsonText);
```

In my api response it is still as `$type` even I want `type`. What is my missing here?

Below one is not my want

```
{
    "message": null,
    "hasError": false,
    "errors": [],
    "data": [
        {
            "version": "1.1",
            "documents": [
                {
                    "documentState": "Correct",
                    "documentData": {
                        "name": "OthersTWN",
                        "$type": "Document",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "DocumentGUID",
                                "$type": "Text",
                                "suspiciousSymbols": null,
                                "recognizedValue": null,
                                "value": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "documentAsBase64": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "percentage": 100
}
```

Below one is my want

```
{
    "message": null,
    "hasError": false,
    "errors": [],
    "data": [
        {
            "version": "1.1",
            "documents": [
                {
                    "documentState": "Correct",
                    "documentData": {
                        "name": "OthersTWN",
                        "type": "Document",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "DocumentGUID",
                                "type": "Text",
                                "suspiciousSymbols": null,
                                "recognizedValue": null,
                                "value": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "documentAsBase64": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "percentage": 100
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have all those `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$type")]` attributes... Can you please [edit] post to clarify if that code is what you *must have* or code that you tried or code that you think should set property name in JSON to "type"?

Comment: Why would you do this? $type - is JSON identifier of class, usually used to distinguish all nested classes. Just make a dto hierarchy of classes. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm